# order by issue with Multiple-record append query in ms access linked table with sql server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, linked-tables

we are selecting the multiple records of the sql server linked ms access tables using the joins and order by clause and inserting the resulting data into another sql server linked table in the ms access by using the Multiple-record append query

here the problem is the inserted table is not maitaining the same order which select query maintains and also observed that if I inserted into the normal access table then order is maintained.

each execution of the Multiple-record append query, inserted lined table holds diferent order.

Answer (score 2):

Rows in a database table have no inherent order, so you should not depend on it. If you need to process data in a specific order, use the `ORDER BY` clause when selecting row out of your table.